# Need help with 2D shooter (blender game engine)

Tags: game-engine

I am trying to make a 2D shooter in the blender game engine just trying to get used to blender. My characther can move jump and shoot but I can't find out how to make him shoot to the left (instead of always right) if he moved to the left. Thanks in advance

Comment: do you have your character turn around when he reverses direction from going left to going right? or does the character's rotation stay constant?

Comment: Currently it just stays constant I know that i need to make him turn but I just can't find a way

Comment: you could have a property, call it "left" set to Boolean. when you push the left arrow to go left, you can assign that property true, and the right arrow will assign it false. You can use that property to control the rotation of the character, or you could have two empties - one parented to the left, and one on the right of your character. Then, depending on the value of "left", one or the other empty could fire.

Comment: I could write an answer going into more detail if you want.

Comment: Its ok. I still didnt try it because I dont have any free time. I will tell you if it worked when I get to try it

Comment: @X-27 hi, sorry for not asking this earlier but how can I make my empties react to the left property if I applied that property to my player. I tried sending a message from the player to the empties but that didnt help because a message is only sent once.
Just to simplify my question: Can you make a property global?
Thanks again